# GitLab Notifications not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a CI pipeline in GitLab where we have the following stages
`build -> test -> deploy`. We are looking to setup the notifications in such a way that if the pipeline has failed then an admin group should get a failed notification. Looking it up on [gitlab notification](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html) page it seems if we setup a custom notification for a group should send a notification but it's only sending to the author of the  pipeline because project notification settings overrides the group notification settings. Can somebody shed some light on this.

Comment: How about doing through publish triggers?

Comment: How about https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/README.html instead ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/notifications.html#issue--epics--merge-request-events *(see the entry in the table on **Failed pipeline**)* only the author will get the email notification, when you setup the custom notification.

You can activate emails on failure by going on GitLab to Project -> Settings -> Integrations -> Project services -> Pipelines emails and write the email addresses of the concerned persons.